# django template engine extends "base.html fails base.html in own file template in other

Tags: django, templates

I have the following structure as far as project

```
django blog <---root
     templates
          base.html
__init__.py
settings.py 
etc etc.py
posts
   migrations
   templates
       post-detail.html
       post-list.html
       post-form.html
```

in my post-detail.html I have

```
{% extends"base.html" %}
```

To which I receive the following error:

```
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/webFullStack/djangoBlog/src/djangoblog/templates/base.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/webFullStack/djangoBlog/src/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/base.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/webFullStack/djangoBlog/src/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/base.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/webFullStack/djangoBlog/src/djangoblog/posts/templates/base.html (Source does not exist)
Error during template rendering

In template /home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/webFullStack/djangoBlog/src/djangoblog/posts/templates/post_form.html, error at line 1
```

my template engine is set up like this in my settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], #join templates folder to root (base) Directory of project
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I am really not sure what is going on here. My understanding is that the template engine as it is set in the settings is to go to the root folder of my project, grab all the templates, and then go though all my apps and grab the templates too. Shouldn't this work?

Comment: I think that `templates` folder should be one level higher (i.e. in `djangoblog` and not `djangoblog/djangoblog`), if your depiction of the structure is accurate and `djangoblog` and `posts` are at the same level.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida so I checked that and here is my file path. it is correct: `/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/webFullStack/djangoBlog/src/djangoblog/templates`

Comment: Ok, but then you may want to fix the structure you included in the post, because this means `django blog` is not at the same level of `posts`, right? If the file is where Django says "Source does not exist", have you checked file permissions?